# loading .mat file written by GPU

Tags: matlab, save, gpu

I have a `.mat` file that was saved after some GPU functions (e.g. `gpuArray`) with `save(['foo.mat'], 'foo', '-v7.3');`.

Now, I am trying to load this `.mat` file, and I do not have a GPU. I get the following error:

> FATAL: Error inserting nvidia (/lib/modules/2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko): No such device
>   Error using load
>   No supported GPU device was found on this computer. To learn more about
>   supported GPU devices

I have no problem loading the file while I have access to GPU. Is there any way to load this file without a GPU?

Comment: What about saving it without GPU? It doesnt make much sense to have .mat with GPUarrays on them....

Comment: @AnderBiguri how to do that?

Comment: are you saving them? or do you already have them saved? I am just confused in general, I find it quite weird that matlab allows to save data on the GPU... That just does not make much sense (to me at least), as GPU memory is used similarly as RAM memory... Anyway, when you are writting GPU code and you want to get your data to the CPU (for example to save it), use `gather()`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot load a `gpuArray` stored in a `.mat` file on a machine that cannot itself create a `gpuArray`. (MATLAB requires that objects loaded from `.mat` files become instances of the original class that they were saved as). Your best bet is to call `gather` on your `gpuArray`s before `save`ing them.

(One reason why MATLAB supports saving and loading `gpuArray` data directly without enforcing the `gather` is to be compatible with other parallel language features such as `parfor`, `spmd`, and `parfeval`).

Comment: What do you mean " to be compatible "?  How?  You are saying you can save a GPU array in a .mat and open it in a parfor, without gather? How does that even work?  (honest question)

Comment: What I mean is that to make the following work: `x = gpuArray(1), parfor idx= 1:1, assert(isa(x, 'gpuArray')); end`, then it must be possible to save/load `gpuArray`s.